# Unity: Access HLSL file like a TextAsset?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assets, hlsl

I would like to expose a public property in my script from which I can drag and drop an `.hlsl` file onto the script component in the inspector window, like in this image, which shows an exposed property to drop a `TextAsset`:

[image: Unity inspector window]

The code powering this is:

```
public class NativeSDKWrapper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset ShaderFile;
    
    // ...
}
```

According to [the Unity Manual page on `TextAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextAsset.html), `.hlsl` is not listed as a supported file type. How can I get around this?

I need to read in the contents of an HLSL file to a string, so that I can compile it with `D3DCompile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Editor class [`ScriptedImporter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetImporters.ScriptedImporter.html) to handle this in your editor:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor.AssetImporters;
using System.IO;

[ScriptedImporter(1, "hlsl")]
public class CubeImporter : ScriptedImporter
{
    public override void OnImportAsset(AssetImportContext ctx)
    {
        var ta = new TextAsset(File.ReadAllText(ctx.assetPath));
        ctx.AddObjectToAsset("main obj", ta);
        ctx.SetMainObject(ta);
    }
}
```

Code based on documentation code linked above.

Be sure to put it in your project's `Editor` folder, as it references Editor  stuff that won't be accessible once built.